# Concise way of saying "risks that came into fruition"

Tags: word-choice

What is a better way of saying "Risks that came to fruition"?

**Context:**

1. I've written about the risks that may occur in a project
2. I've written about the project work itself
3. I need to reflect upon the risks that could have happened (discussed in the first part) and did.

**Examples:** (but not quite right)

- Manifested Risks
- Risks Outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a risk indeed did occur during a project it has [***materialized***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/materialize).

> Definition of materialize in English:
>   verb
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>
> 1. Become actual fact; happen:
>      *'the forecast rate of increase did not materialize'*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/materialize

Comment: or a risk has **emerged**.

Comment: ...risks were realized.